# How to order selected data based on nested table in ASP.NET CORE Code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-mvc

I have three tables **Category**, **Article**, and **Comment**, each category has many articles and each article has many comments.
I want to select all categories ordered by **count of comments** in all articles in each category.
I can only select all categories ordered by articles count like that:

```
var query = context.Categories.AsQueryable();

query = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.Articles.Count).Select(a => a);
```

But i cannot select all categories ordered by count of comments in all articles in each category.

Category class:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public String CategoryName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

Article class:

```
public class Article
{
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }

    public String ArticleAddress { get; set; } 

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public Category category { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment class:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int CommentID { get; set; }

    public String CommentContent { get; set; }

    public int ArticleID { get; set; }

    public Article Article { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SelectMany](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2008/10/10/use-linqs-selectmany-method-to-flatten-collections/) is handy for things like this:

```
var categoriesByCommentCount = query
    .Select(c => new
    {
        c.CategoryId,
        c.CategoryName, 
        CommentCount = c.Articles.SelectMany(r => r.Comments).Count()
    })
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.CommentCount)
    .ToList();
```